# IF operator in mysql issue

Tags: mysql

this is my query:

```
SELECT d.name, d.department_id, d.email , if (d.status = 1, 'Active', 'Inactive') as status  dep.name as dep_name FROM doctors d INNER JOIN departments dep ON  dep.id = d.department_id
```

I want to select the status , if it is 1 then status will be "Active" else "Inactive". How can I do that?

At the moment when i execute my query, a message error appears:

```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'dep.name as dep_name FROM doctors d INNER JOIN departments dep
> ON dep.id = d.de' at line 1
```

Can you help me with this ? thx

Answer (score 3):

Though you have missed a `,` **between status and dep_name**

But In SQL you should use `CASE`:

```
SELECT d.name, d.department_id, d.email , 
CASE WHEN d.status = 1 
       THEN 'Active' 
       ELSE 'Inactive' 
 END  as status,
dep.name as dep_name FROM doctors d 
INNER JOIN departments dep ON  dep.id = d.department_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE statement

```
case when <Condition>  then <value> else <value> end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma after the expression:

```
SELECT d.name, d.department_id, d.email,
       if(d.status = 1, 'Active', 'Inactive') as status,
-------------------------------------------------------^
       dep.name as dep_name
FROM doctors d INNER JOIN
     departments dep
     ON  dep.id = d.department_id;
```

Although I might prefer `case` because it is ANSI-standard, your problem is a missing comma.